# open mysql port to only frontend machine in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have two virtual machines in my Azure deployment.   The first is my frontend web VM instance and the second is a VM instance with a mysql database.   Is it possible to define a network topology such that only my frontend instance can connect to my database instance?  Adding an endpoint on the instance seems to open the port to the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the VMs to a Virtual Network you don't need to add an endpoint on the MySQL instance, just open up the necessary ports on the firewall for that particular instance.  It won't expose any external endpoints.

I cover a similar scenario involving Couchbase in a few blog posts [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/06/16/couchbase-on-azure-creating-a-virtual-network.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/06/16/couchbase-on-azure-creating-virtual-machines.aspx).

**EDIT:**

With Linux VMs in the current preview phase, using a Virtual Network is not supported. The option to do so is blocked in the portal, but [achievable with PowerShell cmdlets](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforLinux/thread/9fac0acd-7d44-4061-8f39-46bbdb54b665/). It's unclear at this point if that's sufficient to achieve the same result as you can with Windows VMs.

Comment: Thanks Jim - does adding the machines to the same subnet within a virtual network provide this?   (I'm not seeing any network connectivity between the Linux VMs unless I add an endpoint)

Comment: yes, when they are on the same subnet they should be able to see each other.  When you remote into one of the Linux VMs you should be able to nslookup the other VM in that subnet. In full disclosure, I've done this with Windows Server VMs not Linux, so not sure if there's another step required here.

Comment: Wierd - I might be missing something or this might be why Azure is still in preview for VMs, but putting all my VMs in the same virtual network and subnet did not seem to solve the issue - still no connectivity between machines.  Opening up an endpoint and then using iptables on the individual hosts to lock down the ports to only specific sources works.

Comment: after some poking around, appears support for Virtual Networks for Linux VMS isn't official yet (and blocked in the portal) - as you noted it's all still preview. I'm not sure that's the specific cause of the problem, but given it's not locked down yet, going the route you have discovered seems prudent.